# Arduino Yun can no longer send to Dropbox

Tags: arduino-yun, python, linux

A long time ago I had set up an Arduino Yun to send files to Dropbox... I tried now and it ends in "killed" when trying to install the latest Dropbox Python module.

`pip install (six, urllib3, etc etc)` does work individually without running out of memory. Unfortunately when I install all but Dropbox, and then put the Dropbox module code folder in the current directory, it does start to import Dropbox with `import dropbox` but ends up with the KILLED message.

Is there a way I can connect to my current Dropbox without it using all of the 60mb of RAM and quitting... I keep getting the error with version 2.1:

> Error.Cannot connect to Dropbox
>   [400] u'v1_retired'

Comment: Have you configured any swap space on your Yun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd eventually figured out how to do it running the latest Dropbox module installed into the sd card where there was room.